# How to scrape content from HTML tree without attribute value

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm having issues scraping html data and getting specific fields. Here's the html code:

````
```

<li class="highlight">
                                                    Relationship Issues
                                            </li>
<li class="highlight">
                                                    Depression
                                            </li>
<li class="highlight">
                                                    Spirituality
                                            </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>, <div class="spec-list attributes-issues">
<h5 class="spec-subcat">Issues</h5>
<div class="col-split-xs-1 col-split-md-2">
<ul class="attribute-list copy-small">
<li class="">
                                                            ADHD
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Alcohol Use
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Anger Management
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Antisocial Personality
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Anxiety
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Behavioral Issues
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Bipolar Disorder
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Borderline Personality
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Career Counseling
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Child or Adolescent
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Chronic Illness
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Chronic Pain
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Coping Skills
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Divorce
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Domestic Abuse
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Domestic Violence
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Eating Disorders
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Emotional Disturbance
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Family Conflict
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Grief
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Internet Addiction
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Life Coaching
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Life Transitions
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Marital and Premarital
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Men's Issues
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Narcissistic Personality
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Obsessive-Compulsive (OCD)
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Parenting
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            School Issues
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Self Esteem
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Self-Harming
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Stress
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Suicidal Ideation
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Transgender
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Trauma and PTSD
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Women's Issues
                                                    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>, <div class="spec-list attributes-mental-health">
<h5 class="spec-subcat">Mental Health</h5>
<div class="col-split-xs-1 col-split-md-2">
<ul class="attribute-list copy-small">
<li class="">
                                                            Dissociative Disorders
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Elderly Persons Disorders
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Impulse Control Disorders
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Mood Disorders
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Personality Disorders
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Psychosis
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Thinking Disorders
                                                    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>, <div class="spec-list attributes-sexuality">
<h5 class="spec-subcat">Sexuality</h5>
<div class="col-split-xs-1 col-split-md-2">
<ul class="attribute-list copy-small">
<li class="">
                                                            Bisexual
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Lesbian
                                                    </li>
<li class="">
                                                            Gay
                                                    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>]

```
````

here's my code:

````
```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html
import html5lib
import re
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
URL = "https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/gary-l-phillips-northfield-il/43578"


page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, parser='html5lib', features="lxml")

specialties = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'spec-list attributes-top'})
issues = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'spec-list attributes-issues'})
mental_health = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'spec-list attributes-mental-health'})
sexuality = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'spec-list attributes-sexuality'})

```
````

The ideal outcome is to have a csv (or excel) file that has output of:

```
Name: {name}
Location: {location}
Phone Number: {Phone_number}
Specialties: {Specialities_{count}}
Issues: {Issues_{count}}
Mental Health Care: {Mental_Health_{count}}
```

I'd like to feed it a general directory website and have the code scrape the html data for those fields. The url is: https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/gary-l-phillips-northfield-il/43578
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get required information from the page, you can use this example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/gary-l-phillips-northfield-il/43578'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'ozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

name = soup.select_one('h1[itemprop="name"]').get_text(strip=True)
location = soup.select_one('.address-data').get_text(strip=True, separator=' ')
phone_number = soup.select_one('.phone-number').get_text(strip=True, separator=' ')
specialties = [li.get_text(strip=True) for li in soup.select('h5:contains("Specialties") + div li')]
issues = [li.get_text(strip=True) for li in soup.select('h5:contains("Issues") + div li')]
mental_health = [li.get_text(strip=True) for li in soup.select('h5:contains("Mental Health") + div li')]

print('Name:')
print(name)
print('Location:')
print(location)
print('Phone Number:')
print(phone_number)
print('Specialties:')
print(*specialties, sep=', ')
print('Issues:')
print(*issues, sep=', ')
print('Mental Health')
print(*mental_health, sep=', ')
```

Prints:

```
Name:
Gary L Phillips
Location:
550 Sunset Ridge Rd Northfield, IL 60093
Phone Number:
(847) 212-1496
Specialties:
Relationship Issues, Depression, Spirituality
Issues:
ADHD, Alcohol Use, Anger Management, Antisocial Personality, Anxiety, Behavioral Issues, Bipolar Disorder, Borderline Personality, Career Counseling, Child or Adolescent, Chronic Illness, Chronic Pain, Coping Skills, Divorce, Domestic Abuse, Domestic Violence, Eating Disorders, Emotional Disturbance, Family Conflict, Grief, Internet Addiction, Life Coaching, Life Transitions, Marital and Premarital, Men's Issues, Narcissistic Personality, Obsessive-Compulsive (OCD), Parenting, School Issues, Self Esteem, Self-Harming, Stress, Suicidal Ideation, Transgender, Trauma and PTSD, Women's Issues
Mental Health
Dissociative Disorders, Elderly Persons Disorders, Impulse Control Disorders, Mood Disorders, Personality Disorders, Psychosis, Thinking Disorders
```